# ConstraintViolationException on deleting multiple cascades

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, cascade

I'm having trouble deleting a user off my database using JPA. When a user communicates with another one, a Conversation object is stored in the database, which contains a list of messages of both users. I was hoping that if I delete the user, the conversation will be deleted and the deletion request cascades to the messages, but it seems that cascading deletion doesn't work for the Message class.

Error message:

> org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not
> execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint
> ["FK6YSKK3HXW5SKLWGI25Y6D5U1L: PUBLIC.MESSAGE FOREIGN
> KEY(CONVERSATION_ID) REFERENCES PUBLIC.CONVERSATION(ID) (1)"; SQL
> statement: delete from conversation where id=? [23503-200]]; nested
> exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException:
> could not execute statement

```
public class User {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "userFrom")
    private List<Conversation> conversations;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "userTo")
    private List<Conversation> conversationsBy;
}

public class Conversation {

    @ManyToOne
    private User userFrom;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User userTo;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade= CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "conversation")
    private List<Message> messages;
}

public class Message {

    @ManyToOne
    private Conversation conversation;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User userFrom;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn
    private User userTo;

    String msg;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to annotate userTo conversations with CASACDE ALL, but I doubt it would succed either. It's very complicated with the user beeing on both ends of an conversation

Comment: @Turo That's intentional. If the conversation would be deleted the receiver of that conversation shouldn't be deleted with it.

Comment: What SQL statements do you see in the log? Seems like there are still `Message` instances referring to a `Conversation` that is about to be deleted.